# Weird Behavior From UI Mask

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a 2D UI health bar using a mask.  I have a black background image, a green health bar image for the full portions of the health bar, and a gray mask image for the depleted portion of the health bar.  The black background is about 1 x .1 in size, and the green and gray portions are slightly smaller so that a small portion of the black background is visible around the edges of the health bar.

When I add the health bar to my scene, I only see the black background.  If I turn off the `Mask` script, the green portion shows through.  The strangest thing is that if I increase the width of the green part to a large number like 50, then the entire bar turns green (except for the thin black border).  Then if I change the `Fill Amount` the bar stays full from 0.51 to 1, and it's empty from 0 to 0.49.  Moving the `Fill Amount` between 0.49 and 0.51 does shrink and expand the green portion of the bar.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnwJF.jpg) is the hierarchy of the health bar.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z7NK.jpg) is the status bar canvas in the Inspector.  The `Render Mode` is `World Space`.  I don't know if that's relevant to this problem.  I have my own script called `Status Bar Canvas Script` attached, but I commented out all of the code.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJJbC.jpg) is the status bar background (the black border) in the Inspector.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTAZq.jpg) is the mask (the unfilled gray bar) in the Inspector.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpJzD.jpg) is the green bar in the Inspector.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMVRc.jpg) is what the result looks like.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2cEo.jpg) is what the result looks like if I uncheck the `Mask` script.

It seems like the problem is related to how Unity is scaling my "Content" object in the scene, but I can't figure out what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both mask holder and FillAmount Prefab have to contain UI Image component and sprite in them. `MaskHolder` will have the mask sprite and `Content` will have the health bar sprite in it. `MaskHolder` will also have a `Mask` component in it and `Show Mask Graphics` is selected. Your hierarchy setup should be like below:

[image]

And shouldn't use a canvas just for a health bar.

Comment: What do you mean I shouldn't use a canvas just for a health bar.  Don't I need a canvas to draw UI elements without using `OnGUI` (which seems to be recommended against)?  I'm new to Unity, so maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: One canvas can have most of the UI objects as children as needed such as Buttons, Background, Texts. Can create empty `Rect` objects in a canvas that have single task oriented objects in it to handle as a group. So when whenever you need buttons active the buttons holding object. Multi canvas is required for example when you needed to place this both screen space such as camera and overlaid. You can keep most of the UI objects in one canvas. Doesn't need a canvas just for health bar. It can be image or an empty object just holding health bar as a child of the same canvas used for other propose